# How to fix VBA routine which is unable to get Forecast Property from Worksheet function please

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

first-time post, so please excuse basic questions. And I'm just learning VBA...

I have inherited an Access database "front end" for reporting from a SQL database.

Until the turn of the new financial year, 1st April all code ran fine.

But I'm updating queries and routines for 2019/20 and have encountered a Run time error 1004 "Unable to get the Forecast property of the WorksheetFunction class"

When I switch to debug in the VBA editor I am directed to this line of code:

```
dblForecast = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Forecast(CDbl(dtDate - 1), intKnownSurg, dblKnownDates)
```

But the routine should be putting the array output into a table named t_Activity_Surgery_FinancialYear, which is referenced in the code.

However, this table is now empty, although the design view shows the correct field names and data types.

Normally I would expect to run the routine and the table above would be populated with the most recent data. Not stay empty.

The assumption I'm making is that xlApp.WorksheetFunction above is no longer available or its range is too small or not correctly defined. But I can't locate it to change this.

Can anybody help with this, please?

Here's the section of code I think is causing the issue. I appreciate any suggestions.

```
    ' Calculate our year-end forecast based on activity to date
    dblForecast = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Forecast(CDbl(dtDate - 1), intKnownSurg, dblKnownDates)
        
    ' Now save our array to our output table
    Set rsOutput = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strOutputTable)
    For i = 0 To UBound(varArray)
        If IsDate(varArray(i, 0)) Then
            rsOutput.AddNew
            rsOutput("ProcDate") = varArray(i, 0)
            rsOutput("Trajectory") = varArray(i, 3)
            If varArray(i, 0) < Date Then
                ' Only provide rolling total figures upto the current date
                rsOutput("Surgeries") = varArray(i, 1)
                rsOutput("Surgeries_RT") = varArray(i, 2)
            ElseIf varArray(i, 0) = Date Then
                ' Only provide rolling total figures upto the current date
                rsOutput("Surgeries") = varArray(i, 1)
                rsOutput("Surgeries_RT") = varArray(i, 2)
                ' Set our current & last year's rolling activity
                rsOutput("PositionToday") = varArray(i, 2)
                rsOutput("TargetToday") = varArray(i, 3)
            ElseIf varArray(i, 0) = dtEndDate Then
                If dtEndDate <= Date Then
                    ' This is either the last day of the year or we are looking back
                    ' on a past year, so only show the target figure (not forecast)
                    rsOutput("Target") = 405
                Else
                    ' Set our forecast and target on the last date in the range
                    rsOutput("Forecast") = dblForecast
                    rsOutput("Target") = 405
                End If

            End If

            rsOutput.Update
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Housekeeping
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    rsInput_TY.Close
    rsOutput.Close
    xlApp.Quit
        
    Set rsInput_TY = Nothing
    Set rsOutput = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.forecast) indicates that the Forecast feature is deprecated in newer versions of office. Other versions of the Forecast method (`.Forecast_ETS`?) might have the same effect. It also appears that the 1004 error comes if there isn't enough data to compute the forecast. In the line that you gave, `intKnownSurg` and `dblKnownDates` should be arrays, but we can't tell from this code segment. Where is the data in those variables coming from? That might be your problem.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it looks like `.Forecast` was probably replaced with `.Forecast_Linear`. That alone might fix the problem. If it does, let me know and I'll transfer this comment to an answer.